# How to add an Array into Set properly?

Tags: java, set

I'm trying to add in Integer array into Set as following,

```
int[] arr = { 2, 6, 4 , 2, 3, 3, 1, 7 }; 
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

I'm getting some error telling as following,

```
myTest.java:192: error: no suitable constructor found for HashSet(List<int[]>)
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
                       ^
constructor HashSet.HashSet(Collection<? extends Integer>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
      inferred: int[]
      upper bound(s): Integer,Object)
constructor HashSet.HashSet(int) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to int)
 where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T>asList(T...)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to        get full output
   1 error
```

Secondly, I also tries as following and still getting error,

```
int[] arr = { 2, 6, 4 , 2, 3, 3, 1, 7 }; 
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>( );
Collections.addAll(set, arr);
```

How to add an Integer array into Set in Java properly ? Thanks.

Comment: Try ```new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(2, 6, 4 , 2, 3, 3, 1, 7))```.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use the wrapper type to use `Arrays.asList(T...)`

```
Integer[] arr = { 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 7 };
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

**or** add the elements manually like

```
int[] arr = { 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 7 };
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int v : arr) {
    set.add(v);
}
```

Finally, if you need to preserve insertion order, you can use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

Comment: Will it work with char Array?

Answer (score 5):

Since Java 8, you can use Stream.

```
int[] arr = { 2, 6, 4 , 2, 3, 3, 1, 7 };

Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

> `myTest.java:192: error: no suitable constructor found for HashSet(List<int[]>)`

Note that arrays in java are `Objects` so `Arrays.asList(int[])` will internally consider `int[]` as a single element. So, `<T> List<T> asList(T... a)` will create `List<int[]>` instead of `List<Integer>` and so you can not create `Set<Integer>` from collection of array (not `Integer` elements).

Possible solutions could be, just use `Integer`(wrapper class) instead of `int` (primitive type).(Which is already stated by `Elliott Frisch`).

If you are using `Java-8` and getting `int[]` and can not change to `Integer[]`,

```
int[] arr = { 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 7 };
Integer[] wrapper = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(wrapper));
```

Moreover, as pointed out by `Louis Wasserman`, if you are using `java-8` you can directly collect array elements to the `Set`.

```
Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: If you're already using streams, you might as well write `Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(toSet())` rather than going via the array.

Answer (score 2):

You trying to insert into `Set` `int` values, but your `Set` stores `Integer`.

Change

`int[] arr = { 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 7 };`

to

```
Integer[] arr = { 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 7 };
```

Also as you are going to create a Set out of Array of Integers, remember that Integers have a special cache pool for Integer between range `-127 to +128`. All Integer objects with value within this range refer to same objects in pool. Hence no new memory will be allocated for Integers in the Set.